# Send link to direct user with Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have an app, which uses iOS SDK from Facebook. I want to share a link wia Messenger app. Currently, I'm able to open "Share dialogue" where the user is selecting recipients. The question is, is there an opportunity to open share dialogue with specific user?
I've tried specify peopleIDs parameter for ShareLinkContent of Facebook SDK, but it doesn't help.

Comment: I've made some research and due to Facebook privacy policy it is not possible